# Difference between React.FC and FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tslint, react-functional-component

What is the difference between React.FC and FC?

```
const Component: React.FC = ({ className }) => <div className={className}></div>
```

The above code causes lint warning. `Property 'className' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)`

```
const Component: FC = ({ className }) => <div className={className}></div>
```

But this code looks fine (at least in VSCode).

```
  ...
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ]
```

I have this in settings.json

Is there any difference between FC vs React.FC?

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your question & the code provided. But can you please provide and example of you wanting to use/implementation of this component. As far as I can see... the issue is to do with you not providing the right props. If you want to see the props available to you as a quick tip, try this:  `const foo: FC = (props) =>  { console.log(props); return <div className={props.className}></div> }`
Side note. `Component` is reserved React class type, so please name the component something else (just ruling out potential issues). Also can you show your `imports`

Comment: Can you share your `import` statements?